# While looping through Lable IDs which are stored in string[] a cannot assaign Text to that IDs

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have lake 100+ label in my web forms project. Each of the labels should display number which iam getting from datatable. I dont want to write 100+ queries so I created foreach loop. The query part works fine but when I want to assign id.Text = rows.Length.ToString(); I get 'string' does not contains definition for 'text'. Can someone help me?

```
string[] ids = { "B01", "B02", "B03", "B04", "A0404" };
            foreach (var id in ids) {
                DataRow[] rows = dataTable.Select("LOCATION LIKE '" + id + "%'");
                id.Text = rows.Length.ToString();
                foreach (DataRow row in rows) {
                filterDT.ImportRow(row);
                }   
            }
```

Comment: `string` does not have a `Text` property. `id` is of type `string`, so it does neither. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Fill the array with the labels.

Comment: Ok. Just that their ID and the Label instance is not the same thing. You would either need an array of those labels themselves, or get the Label by Id, then access its Properties.

Comment: ... it's like I cannot ask your name a question. But I can call you by your name and then ask you as soon as I have your attention :) Makes sense?

Comment: So i have labels with IDs : "B01", "B02", "B03", "B04", "A0404"
those same IDs are used for products in database which is pulled to datatable
so for example I want to count how many product there are with id B01% (B01A,B01B...)
and display the count to the label with id B01

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
            string[] ids = { "B01", "B02", "B03", "B04", "A0404" };
            for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++)
            {
                DataRow[] rows = dataTable.Select("LOCATION LIKE '" + ids[i] + "%'");
                ids[i] = rows.Length.ToString();
                foreach (DataRow row in rows)
                {
                    filterDT.ImportRow(row);
                }
            }
```